# Connecting azure relay service with Bot emulator

Tags: botframework, azure-relay, bot-emulator

I am using azure relay service - hybrid connection as tunneling service. When I try to connect to the azure relay service from bot emulator, getting [POST401directline.conversationUpdate].

Note: ngrok is blocked by our organization, so using azure relay service

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftPassword` you are using with your bot is the same you are passing into Emulator when you attempt to connect.

Additionally, double check that the relay messaging address used in Emulator is correct. If I have set up a relay with an address of `https://my-relay.servicebus.windows.net/relay-service/`, then the messaging address would look like:

`https://my-relay.servicebus.windows.net/relay-service/api/messages`

Hope of help!